# How can I programatically assign a MaxLength to a dynamically created CheckBox?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, ascx, maxlength

On my Sharepoint WebPart (in my .ascx.cs file), I'm conditionally creating various controls/elements programatically, e.g.:

```
CheckBox ckbxEmployeeQ = new CheckBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "ckbxEmp"               
};
ckbxEmployeeQ.Text = "Employee?";
ckbxEmployeeQ.Width = 80;
```

I want to be able to set the MaxWidth property, but it is neither available this way:

```
CheckBox ckbxEmployeeQ = new CheckBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "ckbxEmp",
    MaxLength = 12               
};
```

...nor this way:

```
CheckBox ckbxEmployeeQ = new CheckBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "ckbxEmp"               
};
ckbxEmployeeQ.Text = "Employee?";
ckbxEmployeeQ.Width = 80;
ckbxEmployeeQ.Style.MaxLength = 12;
```

How can I accomplish it?

### UPDATE

Wow, that was a really dumb question (yes, there are dumb questions - at least one, anyway)! In fact, this is the poster child for "TBYP" (Think Before You Post). What I really want to do is set the Width and MaxLength of the TextBox that is affected by the state of the checkbox. and the following does work:

```
boxSSNOrITIN = new TextBox
{
    CssClass = "dplatypus-webform-field-input",
    ID = "txtbxSSNOrITIN",
    Width = 80,
    MaxLength = 12
}
```

Comment: MaxLength is the nomenclature used for the length of strings and other variable-length objects.  A checkbox only has two states, it seems a little counterintuitive that it would have such a property.

Comment: My bad; I was obviously confused (due to my lack of chocolate today, I think).